# Javascript Error in Chrome: Me, something I'm missing or a bug in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I doubt the last option, but probably one of the first two. Can anybody tell me which?

I'm getting the error in the screen shot.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var html = "<script></script>";
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Screenshot of Error]

Comment: What last option? Your question is very vague.

Comment: Sorry, bad joke. The options in the title were, Me, something I've missed or a bug in Chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use \ to render that character correctly:

```
var html = "<script><\/script>";
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a problem in every browser, the script block is terminated at the first string `</script>`, so if that string appears in your code anywhere it will cause a premature termination of the script block.

If you want to have this as a variable in JS, use:

```
var html = unescape("%3Cscript%3E%3C/script%3E");
```

Comment: Etiquette would suggest that you selected steveukx's answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

That's no bug. It's the correct behaviour for a script tag, what you're doing is the equivalent of not escaping a quote in a string.

```
var string = 'My mother's awesome.';
```

An easy way to fix your issue is to break apart the `</script>` tag, like so:

```
var html = "<script></"+"script>";
```